# Boxplot beside a stacked barplot of the means

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have some data I want to represent as a stacked barplot. The data looks more or less like the following:

```
timer_name time
timerA     10%
timerB     20%
timerC     50%
timerD     20%
timerA     5%
timerB     20%
timerC     60%
timerD     15%
...
```

I am plotting the `timer_names` as a stacked barplot, I am currently doing this by using the `aggregate` function to compute the mean of the distribution for each timer, not difficult.

Beside this plot I would also like to show the distribution of the data using a boxplot. It should be looking like the following picture I made.

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

is it possible to achieve this in R, how? Not strictly required, but it would be graphically nice if the height of the boxes (in the boxplot) are propotional to their % in the barplot (as shown in the figure).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could make side by side plots in a single window using `layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2),byrow=T)`, then the barplot command, then boxplot command. In boxplot, the width or varwidth options might help you with the box heights.